# How do I fill holes around a light switch?

Tags: repair, plaster, light-fixture

I have a light switch where the plaster board around the edges of the face plate have broken away.

[image: Holey light switch batman]

I was thinking of using some kind of filler like Polycell to fill the holes but I'm not really sure how I would go about it.  Is it simply a case of mixing the filler quite thick and applying to the holes?

I don't know if this is relevant but the back plate behind the light switch isn't attached to the wall in anyway. The back plate seems to be stay in place by screwing in the light switch.

Comment: What is behind the face plate?  In the US there would be a junction box (similar to [this](http://lh4.googleusercontent.com/public/sSw5NZ4kk6XBxFLNVGPOJzchIR7ggQINGgrtshdSWmOIRmbp9OfFHkeFlwN-wve8U73AJut402rYpykBZ89GiPoDom3t2qcBV9ecj4cGeSAWBRfjrPSMqEsjudZwz2perREsll9Mt79GqQA86VECgrpQlhCi1gVniz7LCI9k4X2quoqmPmBx_UxZjlM_picEQsgq4xWLKN6qnpKOiT3p2BeTUwl0bcP9h4awBVkJFNxs5CmLSVSoPCZnbobC8TEctcitIP6YCr9kc4AKoknwrASQoloy0OaR29AWsrd42csDHRgzGeOtlbIrTAtOpZ3eTxL7-H0rfAWcxT8zx5mqU_8EeWDPV-s4yREoTYDScbHC)).

Comment: @Tester101: The box behind the face plate looks similar to [this one](http://www.reid-electrical.co.uk/sites/reid/images/cat/products/SB632%201.jpg)

Comment: Is the box properly secured?

Comment: If the box isn't secured to framing lumber, you might as well fix it right since you'll be plastering and painting anyways.   Open up the wall enough to secure the box correctly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Pick up a small bucket of an all purpose patch like[Dap Flexall All Purpose Filler](http://www.destinationpaint.com/QT-Flexall-All-Purpose-Filler-p/350710.htm?click=13). The all purpose stuff is a little thicker than typical joint compound, so it makes filling a bit easier.[image]
- Remove the switch cover.
- Using a taping knife, fill in the holes by pushing the compound into the hole and drawing the knife away from the hole.

[image]

Like so...

[image]

- Repeat for each hole.
- Wait for patch to dry.
- Sand, Prime, Paint, Reattach the face plate.

---

If you find the holes are too big, and the compound is just falling through the hole.  You'll have to get a wall repair patch kit, to fill the holes before covering them with compound/plaster.  Follow the directions on the patch kit.

[image]

Comment: This looks to be what I need to do. My only concern is the electrical box. As mentioned above, it isn't attached to the plaster board at all. It only stays in place once the light switch has been screwed in.

Comment: @Barry Hmmm. That seems odd.  You might need a new box.  In the US they make what's call an "old work" box, they have little tabs that allow it to pinch the wall to hold it in place.  I would check the local hardware store for something similar, and replace the box before patching the holes.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I think I will purchase one [of these](http://www.screwfix.com/p/appleby-1-gang-47mm-dry-lining-box/83270) before I sort out the plaster.

Comment: If you can place some tape on the backside of the holes to span the width, it would make filling the holes easier on you.

Answer (score 8):

You can use something like this [Wall Repair Patch](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-202271875/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053) to give some support to the new plaster.  Cut out a square in the patch to match the size of the junction box and then put the patch in place (with the face plate off).  Then apply joint compound to those gaps; the patch will give the joint compound some support.  Finally when everything is dry then put the face plate back on.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I am a complete novice at DIY. Won't this fill the hole completely? I just need to repair the holes around the light switch.

Comment: You would cut out a square in the center the size of the junction box.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. doh!

Comment: overkill for the application