# How do I fix these gaps where the socket plates don't cover?

Tags: plaster

Recently had this room plastered, then painted, and stupidly I only took the front off of the sockets instead of removing the full front socket.

This has caused a bit of an issue as the facings now don’t fit right on to the socket, I’ve accepted I’m going to have to deal with that for now.

What I do need fixed is the holes I can see behind a switch & one of the sockets. What is the best course of action here?[image][image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fill holes around a light switch?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10168/how-do-i-fill-holes-around-a-light-switch)

Comment: For someone in the UK... Are "plus sized" outlet covers common/available?  In the US we have a few sizes - Standard, Midway, and Jumbo to take care of these little gaps.

Answer (score 5):

The best approach is to fix the plaster and paint. Some other ideas:

- Install oversize device plates. Since you have nice stainless-steel plates now, this will be more expensive, but it would be quick and easy.
- You may be able to find or make backing plates that fit around the devices, behind the existing plates, and extend outward a small distance.
- As a last resort, fill with spackle or painter's caulk, then touch up the paint.

Answer (score 1):

- Smooth uneven border areas
- Mix new plaster or [already mixed material](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MYU6ZEB)
- Apply the mix on the damaged area
- When it dries apply a thin layer of mud compound
- Sand, prime and paint

Hope this helps